# Percona pt-deadlock-logger doesn't detect deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock, percona

On a server with performance issues, I'm trying to detect deadlocks with Percona's pt-deadlock-logger

I have this line in a crontab file

```
0 * * * * root pt-deadlock-logger --daemonize --run-time=1h --dest D=test,t=deadlocks u=root,h=127.0.0.1
```

Whenever I log into the server I can confirm this is running with ps-ef|grep deadlock

The database and table are set up. My understanding is that I use root access rights, based on  a password set in /root/.my.cnf

I tried to simulate a deadlock with (from here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,193770,193913#msg-193913)

```
create table test.innodb_deadlock_maker(a int primary key) engine=innodb; 
insert into test.innodb_deadlock_maker(a) values(0), (1); 

-- connection 0 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 0; 
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0; 

-- connection 1 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 1; 
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 1 where a <> 1;
```

and this shows a deadloc in the mysql console, but it is not recorded in the database table. Any ideas why not?

Comment: I answered on Oct 3, 2013, and -- in my own opinion -- the answer given resolved the problem. No acceptance, no comment, not to mention no bounty for what appeared to be an important question, despite you being online. Since my answer does not meet your requirements, please see it as a community service that I delete it, in an effort to reduce SO noise. Good luck resolving your performance issues.

Comment: Hi Marc,I have to apologize, I have seen your answer, it seemed correct, but I simply didn't have time to get onto testing it. Will test and award bounty immediately, if you want to repost it. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Thanks, re posted. I know we all can get busy at times. About dead locks, I am investigating this area in particular, so I am curious to know the outcome of this issue.

Comment: Thanks again for reposting. I have to wait for 30 minutes for some reason to award the bounty. Your transaction example works. Its sort of unfortunate as my performance problem is obviosuly not a deadlock, nothing has ever been recorded apart from this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to simulate the deadlock as indicated resulted in this for me:

```
-- connection 0 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 0;
-- does not block, fails immediately with 
-- ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0; 

-- connection 1 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 1; 
-- does block, fails after a timeout with
-- ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 1 where a <> 1;
```

So, connection 1 waits for connection 0, but connection 0 does not wait on connection 1, only on the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` from the application.

This is not a deadlock, and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` does not report a deadlock either.

Changing the sequence to:

```
-- connection 0 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 0;

-- connection 1 
set transaction isolation level serializable; 
start transaction; 
select * from test.innodb_deadlock_maker where a = 1; 

-- connection 0 
-- does block, waiting on connection 1
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0; 

-- connection 1 
-- would deadlock, fails immediately with
-- ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 1 where a <> 1;
```

and this unblocks connection 0:

```
-- connection 0 
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0; 
-- now unblocked, fails with
-- ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

In this case, `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` reports:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2013-10-03 11:57:27 0x7f6b60308700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1297, ACTIVE 47 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1160, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 140099372304128, query id 13 localhost root Searching rows for update
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 0 where a <> 0
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`innodb_deadlock_maker` trx id 1297 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000508; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex a80000011a011c; asc        ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1298, ACTIVE 15 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1160, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 3, OS thread handle 140099152021248, query id 14 localhost root Searching rows for update
update test.innodb_deadlock_maker set a = 1 where a <> 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`innodb_deadlock_maker` trx id 1298 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000508; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex a80000011a011c; asc        ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test`.`innodb_deadlock_maker` trx id 1298 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000508; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex a80000011a0110; asc        ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I can't speak to `pt-deadlock-logger`, but I think it relies on the `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` section in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, so first please make sure this command actually reports a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

I don't answer your question directly. But pt-deadlock-logger needn't add to crontab at all.

Once you run pt-deadlock-logger,  If no --run-time is specified, pt-deadlock-logger runs forever, checking for deadlocks at every interval. And you also can specify the interval by the option -interval. For more information, please check the link below.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-deadlock-logger.html#cmdoption-pt-deadlock-logger--interval